# I can't save a input (HTML and JS)

Tags: javascript, html

Respected friends,

I'm a student of web devel, and self-taught. Also, I'm learning about DOM with Javascript. I am making a simple formulary, with the objective to play with positions, change colors and managing the DOM, etc. I want to create some participators, and display them in a list.

This is the part of my HTML code.

```
<label>Nombre: </label>
<input id="addNombre" type="text"/>
<label>Color :</label>
<input id="addNombre" type="text"/>
<button onclick="AddCompetidor()">Añade Participante</button>
```

I have done and redone many JS functions, this is the last one I have done.

```
function AddCompetidor(){
    var nombre = document.getElementById("addNombre");
    var color = document.getElementById("addColor");
    alert (nombre,color);
}
```

I tried with others functions, how to create an array, but I don’t know if it’s the best way to approach it.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do you need to find a way to create an array with values of the inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the comprehensive solution with comments.

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const list = document.getElementById("list");

// let's handle the form submit event
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  // this will prevent the form from doing network request
  e.preventDefault();

  // lets get input elements from form by their ids
  const { nombre, color } = e.target.elements;

  // lets add new elements in the list
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = `${nombre.value} — ${color.value}`;
  list.appendChild(li);

  // lets clear the form
  nombre.value = "";
  color.value = "";
});
```

```html
      <form id="form">
        <label>Nombre: </label>
        <input id="nombre" type="text" />
        <label>Color :</label>
        <input id="color" type="text" />
        <button>Añade Participante</button>
      </form>
      <ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: You're amazing Sergey, I hope someday to be as good a developer as you are!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an array of HTML input values, use:

```
var array = [nombre.value, color.value]
```

The square brackets define a new array, and getting the `value` parameter gets what's inside the `<input>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

you have to get the correct id of element:

```
<label>Nombre: </label>
<input id="nombre" type="text"/>
<label>Color :</label>
<input id="color" type="text"/>
<button onclick="AddCompetidor()">Añade Participante</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddCompetidor(){
        var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
        alert (nombre + color);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Mustafa, I'll continue my exercise :D

Answer (score -1):

You can define a class

class players{

```
constructor( nombre , color){ 
         this.nombre = nombre; 
         this.color = color;
```

}}
and create as many object and add each object in a array like this

var obj = new players( nombarvalue, colorvalue);

var list = [];

list.push(obj);

then iterate this array of object to print a list

Comment: It creates multiple player objects, but the question asks for just an array.